# Stuck on a a epsilon-delta proof involving radicals

Tags: proof-writing, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to 3}{(x^2+2x-1)\over \sqrt{x+1}} = 7.$$

I've been stuck on this for over an hour now. I've tried using the definition of a limit and reducing $|f(x)- L|$ to make it look like $(x-3)$, but I can't seem to do it. I've also tried bounding $1\over \sqrt{x+1}$, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x^2+2x-1=(x+5)(x-3)+14$.
Therefore
\begin{align*}\frac{(x^2+2x-1)}{\sqrt{x+1}}-7
&=\frac{(x+5)(x-3)}{\sqrt{x+1}}
+\frac{7(2-\sqrt{x+1})}{\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=\frac{(x+5)(x-3)}{\sqrt{x+1}}
+\frac{7(4-(x+1))}{\sqrt{x+1}(2+\sqrt{x+1})}\\
&=\left([x+5
-\frac{7}{(2+\sqrt{x+1})}\right)\frac{(x-3)}{\sqrt{x+1}}
.
\end{align*}
It follows that if $x\in (0,4)$ then
$$\left|\frac{(x^2+2x-1)}{\sqrt{x+1}}-7\right|
\leq \left(4+5
+\frac{7}{(2+1)}\right)|x-3|.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'll try and do it from here. Thanks!